# Testing Schema Update in Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm making an unbounded Dataflow pipeline and want to be sure that a new version of a schema is compatible with an old one so that it can be updated without stopping. If my original object is defined as:

```java
@DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
public class TransactionPojoV1 {
  public final String bank;
  public final double purchaseAmount;

  @SchemaCreate
  public TransactionPojoV1(String bank, double purchaseAmount) {
    this.bank = bank;
    this.purchaseAmount = purchaseAmount;
  }
}
```

And I want to add a new field `fee`:

```java
@DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
public class TransactionPojoV2 {
  public final String bank;
  public final double purchaseAmount;
  public final double fee;

  @SchemaCreate
  public TransactionPojoV2(String bank, double purchaseAmount, double fee) {
    this.bank = bank;
    this.purchaseAmount = purchaseAmount;
    this.fee = fee
  }
}
```

How can i write a test to test whether a `TransactionPojoV2` can be decoded from a `TransactionPojoV1`? And ensure the behaviour is as expected.

The above might fail this test, not sure, but i'd like something along the lines of:

```java
TransactionPojoV1 transactionPojoV1 = ...

byte[] encoded = Coder.encode(transactionPojoV1);

TransactionPojoV2 transactionPojoV2 = Coder.decode(encoded);

// Assert values are as expected.
```

I just can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get get the `Coder` from a `Pipeline`'s `SchemaRegistry`. For the classes given in the question, you could do:

```java
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TransactionPojoTest {
    @Rule
    public TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

    @Test
    public void testTransactionV1toV2() throws NoSuchSchemaException, IOException {
        SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry = p.getSchemaRegistry();

        Coder<TransactionPojoV1> transactionPojoV1Coder = schemaRegistry.getSchemaCoder(TransactionPojoV1.class);
        Coder<TransactionPojoV2> transactionPojoV2Coder = schemaRegistry.getSchemaCoder(TransactionPojoV2.class);

        TransactionPojoV1 inputTransaction = new TransactionPojoV1("Some Bank", 100.0);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        transactionPojoV1Coder.encode(inputTransaction, byteArrayOutputStream);

        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());

        TransactionPojoV2 outputTransaction = transactionPojoV2Coder.decode(byteArrayInputStream);

        assertEquals(inputTransaction.bank, outputTransaction.bank);
        assertEquals(inputTransaction.purchaseAmount, outputTransaction.purchaseAmount, 1e-15);
        assertEquals(0D, outputTransaction.fee.doubleValue(), 1e-15);
    }
}
```

For this to pass, `TransactionPojoV2` needs to be:

```java
@DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
public class TransactionPojoV2 {
    public final String bank;
    public final double purchaseAmount;
    @Nullable public final Double fee;

    @SchemaCreate
    public TransactionPojoV2(String bank, double purchaseAmount, @Nullable Double fee) {
        this.bank = bank;
        this.purchaseAmount = purchaseAmount;
        this.fee = fee != null ? fee : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this could raise some false negatives. Dataflow can be more flexible when new fields are added by re-ordering fields to ensure schema compatibility, but that's not taken into account here.

Answer (score 0):

The Dataflow runner can be more permissive here, as it supports re-ordering fields to ensure update compatibility. If there are new fields, it will move them to the "end" of the Schema, and it will ensure that existing fields are in the same order in the old and new schema.

This all happens transparently to you as a Beam user, it just means that as long as your new Schema only *adds* fields relative to the old Schema, it should be update-compatible.

To test this sort of update compatibility I'd suggest you use something like this:

```java
Schema v1 = schemaRegistry.getSchema(TransactionPojoV1.class);
Schema v2 = schemaRegistry.getSchema(TransactionPojoV2.class);

Set<Field> removedFields = Sets.difference(ImmutableSet.of(v1.getFields()), 
                                           ImmutableSet.of(v2.getFields()));
assertEmpty(removedFields);
```

Note this is just off-the-cuff, I haven't tested it. It also relies on Sets and ImmutableSet from guava.

Also, it's worth noting that Dataflow might be more permissive than this in practice. Dataflow only cares about update compatibility at fusion boundaries (i.e. where there's a GroupByKey/shuffle).

Comment: Does that mean that the `Schema` generated in the `TestPipeline` will not match the `Schema` of the pipeline running on Dataflow? Since the `Schema` includes positions/indexes. Unless it is doing the shuffling after encoding to bytes? That would mean the encode/decode test I suggested isn't actually valid since it isn't testing the same `Schema`. Is that behaviour documented anywhere?

Comment: Or maybe it is the `Coder` that is different?

Comment: Yes the `Schema` will be modified, but it's done in a way that's transparent to the user. There's a layer of indirection (see encoding_position, in schema.proto), which allows runners to set the encoded order of fields, to ensure update compatibility, while keeping the user-defined order in user code.